# Bluetooth data acquisition in background in iPhone 4G S

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to develop an application for the iPhone 4GS that supports Bluetooth 4.

The application would continually listen to the data transmitted by a heart rate monitor over Bluetooth, and show information on a screen.

To achieve this, the application would have to listen to the data even when it's not the active foreground application.

Like Android, is it possible to silently listen to Bluetooth events on an iPhone as a background service?

Comment: Wht is wrong with the question ?

Comment: what are you trying to ask? difficult to trace.

Comment: As it is difficult to trace , does tht mean do vote it down ? 
i am just asking tht is it possible to listen bluetooth data in a background or not

Comment: better it would be that you try to explain with more clarity

Comment: All i wanna know is that like android is it possible to listen bluetooth events as a background service?

Comment: It would help if you included what you've tried to investigate this. Also, it looks like you're looking for a 'yes' or 'no' answer, which wouldn't be very helpful. Please consider _editing_ your question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't determine exactly what you're asking, but here are two tutorials for incorporating Bluetooth in iOS apps:

- [iPhone Bluetooth Programming](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502)
- [iOS Bluetooth Programming - Getting devices to see each other](http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2011/05/bluetooth-programming-getting-devices.html)

Also, here is Apple's list of [Supported Bluetooth profiles](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647).

Answer (score 1):

You won't find serial port profile (SPP) in iOS devices if you're looking for that.
So question about using it in the background would seem irrelevant.

You could use 'old style' FSK modem over BT audio an then decode the signal in
code. On the other hand you should consider going WiFi. Microchips MRF24WB0MA/RM for
example supports adhoc/infrastructure netwroks and it also has Bonjour support.